# Error de permisos a internet

Tags: android, cordova, plugin

Estoy trabajando con `cordova` una aplicación para *Android* que hace uso de internet. Para ello, agrego el plugin ***cordova-plugin-network-information***, el cual se supone que agrega el **permison.INTERNET**, pero al revisar el **manifest.xml**, no aparece por ningún lado, y si se lo agrego, igual no sirve de nada.

El problema radica en que cuando compilo el *APK* en modo depuración, todo funciona bien, pero cuando compilo con la instrucción **`cordova build android --release`**, genera el *APK*, y todo bien (en teoria), ya cuando la firmo y alineo al terminar, aparentemente todo esta bien, pero al instalarla en un teléfono, esta no pide permisos para acceder a internet, y cuando se instala, no deja hacer nada porque no tiene acceso a internet.

**Nota:** Con la *APK* de depuración, sí, funciona todo bien.

Comment: Utilizas Ajax para consumir algun webservice ???

Comment: si utilizo ajax de esta forma:
`$.ajax({
type: "GET",
dataType: "json",
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
crossDomain: true,  
url: urlGetUserList,
async: true,
timeout: 10000,                
success:  function (data, status, jqXHR) {})`

Comment: ok, tu Webservice utiliza el protocolo **https** ???

Comment: si, el servidor apache tomcat que recibe la petición get esta en https

Comment: cual es el error que recibes?

Answer (score 1):

> **Cordova no permite llamadas HTTPS a  servidores con certificados SSL no confiables instalados en ellos**

Hace tiempo yo tuve el mismo problema que tu tienes, y pues navegando por internet me encontré con este interesante articulo:

https://amielynjunryl.wordpress.com/2014/03/01/phonegap-ajax-no-longer-works-when-accessing-https-request-after-exporting-as-signed-apk/

El articulo esta en ingles, lo importante de ese articulo es lo siguiente:

> **La mejor manera de solucionar este problema, es instalar un certificado SSL en el lado del servidor que sea de CONFIANZA en
>   Android OS e iOS.**

Después de haber leído esto lo primero que hice fue cambiar de **https** a **http** para probar, y funciono !!!. Incluso con el APK firmado funcionaba. El problema no era ni el código ni los plugins.

> Entonces el problema era que tenia un certificado **SSL defectuoso** 
>   configurado en el lado del servidor.

Espero que esto pueda ayudarte.

Puedes leer mas sobre SSL [aqui](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl.html)